# Why can't I move a game to the sd card?

Tags: sd-card, app2sd

I read that you cannot move system apps or apps that have widgets to SD card.
This game doesn't provide a widget.

Is there anything I can do to make it move to SD ? Maybe fix something in apk ?

Storage:
Application 8,32 MB
Data 44,00 KB

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: Never put system apps or apps including widgets (if you are using the widgets) to external storage. This can make them misbehave or even force close.**

1. Download Android platform tools [here](http://techgage.com/articles/software/android_moving_to_sd_card/android_x86_64_20140702_platform-tools.zip)
2. Turn on USB debugging on your phone and connect it to your pc (make sure the drivers are installed)
3. Extract the zip file to a directory of choice (on your pc)
4. Open cmd on your pc (assuming you're using Windows) and navigate using cd to where you extracted your platform-tools
5. When you have navigated to the folder using cmd type

   > adb devices

   Check if you see your device on there, it should look something like this: [image: Should look somewhat like this]

   If you can see your device on the list then move on to the next step. If not your drivers are not installed and you need to install them from your manufacturers website
6. Now type
   Android 4.1 and above:

   > adb shell pm get-install-location

   Android 4.0 and below:

   > adb shell pm setInstallLocation 2

   This should return either auto or phone. We need to change this.
7. Now type
   Android 4.1 and above:

   > adb shell pm set-install-location 2

   Android 4.0 and below:

   > adb shell pm setInstallLocation 2

This will switch it from auto to external.

8. Complete! Now you should be able to move apps to sdcard.

Sources:
http://techgage.com/article/moving_your_non-movable_android_apps_to_an_sd_card/

Comment: Please write as much as possible on an answer and as less as possible through links since links can go offline. This will help other users in the future who're experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Sure I'm new xD

Comment: I know, that's why I've been requesting you to do that :) when I've been posting my first answer to someone it was similar with what you did. And just like you I had received a request I gave you :)

Comment: Fixed my mistake :)

Comment: Thanks! That would help the community. Your answer deserves +1. It might also be smart to add this: Apps that Shouldn’t be Moved to the SD Card  Widgets – no matter how menial in usefulness or design. System tools – many might not operate as intended without being on the phone’s storage. Important apps – you don’t want to risk an important app becoming inaccessible when you need it. I can’t stress the above enough, so be wise!